# How to fill outer and inner classes

Tags: spring, mybatis

```
    import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class P {
    private String name;
    private String operationId;

    @Data
    public static class Operation {
        private Timestamp ts;
        private String id;
    }


}
```

I want to fill in the fields of both classes with one query using join

```
  <select id="getAllP" resultType="com.mappers.P">
        SELECT t."name" as name, t."operationId" as operationId,  o."ts" as ts, o."id" as id
        FROM  FROM "P"  t JOIN "Operation" o ON t."operationId" = o."id"  
    </select>
```

If leave `resultType = "com.mappers.P"` in this form, then only the field of the outer class is filled, if `resultType = "com.mappers.P & Operation"` then only the internal one, how to ensure that the fields of both classes are filled? thanks in advance

Comment: The best way would be to create a `<resultMap>` that contains the definition for the outer and the inner `<association>` class. https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#resultMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, although you can go deeper by splitting them into two result maps and building them that way.   Use the documentation above, and you can get super creative.

```
<resultMap id="pMap">
   <result property="name" column="name"/>
   <association type="Operation" columnPrefix="o_">
      <result property="name" column="name"/>
      <result property="ts" column="name"/>
   </association>
</resultMap>

<select id="getAllP" resultMap="pMap">
...
</select>
```